# Efficacy of sonic kangaroo deterrents

Tags: zoology, ethology, behaviour, senses

[Bender (2003)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3784449?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) tested the efficacy of sonic kangaroo deterrents. Their device is static (and apparently ineffective).

Has there been any rigorous testing of the whistle-like 'kangaroo deterrent' devices fitted to the front of vehicles?